# Add space using based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| W | 1 |
| WT | 2 |
| WW | 3 |

trying to create a new column C with space ahead of column A
if B = 1 there is one space in column A, if B= 2 there is 2 "" in A
the output like below, can't show space here, I just use "" as space

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W | 1 | ""W |
| WT | 2 | """"WT |
| WW | 3 | """"""WW |

I am trying to use `df['C'].apply(lambda X: insert_space(X, ""), axis = 1)`
but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

If need add number of spaces by value in `B` use custom lambda function with repeat values by multiple by scalars and add `A` values:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' ' * x.B + x.A, axis=1)
```

Solution with `f-string`s:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{' ' * x.B}{x.A}", axis=1)
```